# Angular hidden element flashes briefly when page appears

Tags: angular, hidden

my.component.html:

```
    <div [hidden]=shouldHideErrorMessage()>Error!</div>
```

my.component.ts:

```
    public shouldHideErrorMessage(): boolean {
      return this.Property == null || this.Property.IsGood
    }
```

The property is initially null, so `shouldHideErrorMessage()` returns true. But the error message flashes on the screen when it loads. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Using `*ngIf` is not a choice?

Comment: I think your condition is not clear use if to check null and why this.Property.IsGood

Answer (score 2):

As Faisal suggested, using *ngIf prevents the problem:

```
<div *ngIf="shouldShowErrorMessage()">Error!</div>
```

Comment: You can also do it like  this: `<div *ngIf="!Property?.IsGood">Error!</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Better use like this
In your component.ts

```
public shouldHideErrorMessage(): boolean {
  if(this.Property == null){
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

and in you component.html

```
<div *ngIf="shouldHideErrorMessage()">Error!</div>
```